# Grab, filter and show this data in PHP

Tags: php, filter

This is example what I mean:
I wanna grab result from this url **web1.com/do.php?id=45944**
Example output:

```
"pk":"bn564vc3b5yvct5byvc45bv","1b":129,"isvalid":true,"referrer":true,"mobile":true
```

Then, I will show data result on other site **web2.com/show.php**
But I just wanna see data value "**pk**", "**1b**" and "**isvalid**". I don't need "**referrer**" and "**mobile**" data.
So, when I access web2.com/show.php, it just show data like this:

```
bn564vc3b5yvct5byvc45bv 129 true
```

1. file_get_contents **web1.com/do.php?id=45944**
2. Grab this result "pk":"bn564vc3b5yvct5byvc45bv","1b":129,"isvalid":true,"referrer":true,"mobile":true
3. Filter and show value "pk", "1b" and "isvalid" on **web2.com/show.php**

So, can you help me with simple php code/script?

Sorry if you don't understand because my english.

Comment: your code effort what you tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this source providing JSON-formatted data?  That is, with { }'s around it?

If so, use PHP's built in json_decode function.  (Man page at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  It will parse the JSON data for you and return an associative array.  For example

```
$your_JSON_data = '{"pk":"bn564vc3b5yvct5byvc45bv","1b":129,"isvalid":true,"referrer":true,"mobile":true}';
$your_array = json_decode($your_JSON_data);
echo $your_array['pk'] . ' ';
echo $your_array['1b'] . ' ';
echo $your_array['isvalid'];
```

If, for some reason, there are no JSON-style curly braces around your data, you can append them.... for example,

```
$proper_JSON = "{$bad_json_data}";
```

however, if that's the case, I'd wonder why it wasn't properly formatted in the first place.  In that case it may be safer to use the PHP explode function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Oh my god. Finally. It work with explode. But I still have little problem. example result: "39ce1831442eb312276bcfb809f36666","qp""YF4lISx9ISgnIX0tIiYlIPwmIl1cWyt8KDF9Kiv3W1c5_iQsICEiLX4jKyT7JjR9KTAj_flwXTAoIv4iMiIoLSB--WNhMCh9","kw"  . how to filter delete colon, coma, qp and kw. so, example final result 39ce1831442eb312276bcfb809f36666 YF4lISx9ISgnIX0tIiYlIPwmIl1cWyt8KDF9Kiv3W1c5_iQsICEiLX4jKyT7JjR9KTAj_flwXTAoIv4iMiIoLSB--WNhMCh9